# Iterate over an object's "public" attributes

Tags: python

Recently, I find myself writing code like this:

```
for name in dir( object ):
    if name.startswith( '__' ) : continue
    ...
```

Is there a more pythonic way to access the object's "public" namespace?

Comment: what problem are you solving in the first place that this construct is useful?

Comment: What about `for name in filter( lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), dir(obj)):` ? Please note that in Python even a single underscore (`_`) is intended to indicate a *"private"* attribute.

Comment: @NiklasR `for name in ( x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') ):` doesn't need filter

Comment: It's curious that the question is being marked a duplicate of a question that was asked 6 months later....

Comment: Also odd that this is happening 5 years after the question was asked!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can prepare list of "public" attributes (as list or as generator) before:

```
>>> public_props = (name for name in dir(object) if not name.startswith('_'))
>>> for name in public_props:
    print name
```

But please read a note about `dir()` function in the documentation:

> **Note** Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

You should also be aware, that any class can implement `__dir__()` method that may return a list of names that do not necessarily correspond to the names of the attributes. In other words, `dir(something)` does not guarantee that the result will return attributes of `something`.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `dir(object)` to `object.__dict__`?

Comment: object.__dict__ doesn't necessarily return the attributes you want, at least from my test results that's the case.

Answer (score 23):

You could use the [`vars` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars) instead.

For example:

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.__foo = 'foo'
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> dir(c)
['_C__foo', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
'__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__',    
'__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',    
'__weakref__']
>>> vars(c)
{'_C__foo': 'foo'}
```

Note that, as Niklas R has pointed out, variables with a single underscore are also considered private. However the `vars()` function has the advantage of eliminating all but the instance variables.

Comment: I get `TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute` when trying this on some other objects

Comment: Yes, the `vars()` function can only be used on objects that have a `__dict__`. So, for example, if `__slots__` is defined on your class then you won't be able to use the `vars()` function.

Comment: Also note that this won't get anything that's a property, so it's not just things with `__slots__` that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than an exclusion branch using the `continue` keyword, iterating over a comprehension of public names directly seems more Pythonic. But it could just be a matter of taste, it's admittedly not much better than what you already have.

```
public_names = (n for n in dir(object) if not n.startswith('_'))
for attr in public_names:
    ...
```

*Note:* Single underscore attributes are also not "public".